# ¿Como resolver problema con flutter en vs code, no me ejecuta apk en dispositivos?

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart, windows11

Al ejecutar, el "Flutter Demo Home Page", tanto en mi movil, el emulador y ap para windows, comienza el lanzamiento pero se detiene y no lo ejecuta. En los exploradores Chrome y Edge si lo ejecuta.
Realice todas las configuraciones recomendadas por la pagina oficial y el flutter doctor no me da errores.
Asimismo ejecuto el "Flutter Demo Home Page" con android studio y funciona perfecto en mi movil, el emulador, chrome, edge y windows.
Cambie a los distintos canales de flutter y hace el mismo error.
Reinstale el sistema operativo y volvi a instalar todo y continua el error, estoy utilizando Windows 11 home.

[image: Les dejo captura del vscode y del flutter doctor]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

1. tienes que levantar el emulador de android para que el IDE lo pueda detectar.
2. una vez levantado **iniciar la depuración**

cuando es la primera vez que se ejecuta el proyecto siempre demora un poco pero si lo levanta

Comment: Muchas gracias HC. valeria, es exactamente lo que hice, con android studio me funciona perfecto, el problema es que usualmente trabajo con VScode y es allí donde no me funciona, me reconoce tanto el emulador como el móvil conectado por USB pero cuando lo ejecuto es como que comienza a ejecutarlo y se interrumpe sin marcar ningún error!

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar el problema: resulta que la ruta donde guardaba mi proyecto era demasiado extensa; guardé mi proyecto en una carpeta en el directorio "C:" y se ejecuta normalmente.